# how can catch event ajax send to server, not waiting for server respond

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, events

My problem is that when user click on link on website, i using jquery to catch event click and ajax to update database 
if i do something like this, it will take a litle time because of the waitting for respond form server

```
$.ajax({
success: function() {
...
window.href = link;
}
});
```

I want something like

```
$.ajax({
alreadysend: function() {
...
}
});
```

I read document ajax, but i can't find any solution for my problem.

**EDIT: i solve my problem, i need to work hard on jQuery, thanks you all**

Comment: Do you mean that you want to execute the AJAX call and still let the user navigate away from the current page?

Comment: You want to prevent the user from pressing the button again until the answer returns from server?

Comment: It sounds like you have a blocking operation due to the database operation taking time. It is not clear what you want to prevent or allow though. Could you give further details please :) ?

Comment: Perhaps you mean to write `window.location.href`?  That is the correct way to redirect a user to a different page.

Comment: thanks for quick reply, when user click on link i using jquery to catch event click and event.preventDefault(); prevent the event to go to this link then i using ajax to send update to my site but in jquery we have beforeSend and success. Both of them do not use in my case, i want something between them it after beforeSend and before success, it like alread send to server but not waitting to server respond

Comment: If you don't specify a callback your code won't wait for a response.

Comment: how can i specify a callback function in my case

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It does that by default since Ajax is asynchronous! If you want code to execute regardless if the server was reached and responded, simply put your executing code after the Ajax block.

On the flip side, if you want to tell if the user already made the submit action, you can use a application-scope variable to toggle on call and completed events. (I.e set to true when the user initiates a Ajax call. On completion, set to false. Disallow the call I already true)

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you just call the function you want to call after the `$.ajax` line? Like this:

```
$.ajax({ ... });
do_things();
```

**Edit** If you want to do a *redirect*, you'll have to wait for the AJAX call to come back to be sure it was successful or not. If you don't care whether it was successful, and just care about it making the call at all, you can place it in the line after the $.ajax call, since the call happens asynchronously. In any case, we need some more information on what you want to achieve exactly.

Comment: Why the downvote? If I misunderstood the question, please let me know. The ajax call will happen asynchronously right after that function call.

Comment: And if the `do_things()` function is a redirect as is indicated in the question?

Comment: Oh, a redirect, I see now. That wasn't stated in the question though.

Comment: i don't want to know success or not, i just want to know it already send or not:-D

Answer (score 1):

Simply call your code just after the call to $.ajax:

```
$.ajax({success: function(){
    // done after server response
}});

// do something immediately after
```

Ajax call is asynchronous, so your script is not blocked.

Answer (score 0):

I am not 100% sure of what you are trying to do, but if you want to wait for the ajax call to return before your code carries on you can set it to do so by setting `async` to false, although its worth noting that this is kind of counter productive and is deprecated in jQuery 1.8.

http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/

> By default, all requests are sent asynchronously (i.e. this is set to
>   true by default). If you need synchronous requests, set this option to
>   false. Cross-domain requests and dataType: "jsonp" requests do not
>   support synchronous operation. Note that synchronous requests may
>   temporarily lock the browser, disabling any actions while the request
>   is active. As of jQuery 1.8, the use of async: false is deprecated.